# Ruby on Rails / Javascript - How to tell if content was generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application that uses a CMS to render content in the view pages.

I'd like to be able to know if a certain HTML tag has content that was generated by the CMS.

For example, in my `index.html.haml`, I could have:

```
%p= @instance_variable.content
```

If I hover over the `<p>` tag in the front-end pages, I'd like to have a popup of some sort telling me it has content generated by a CMS.

Can this be done automatically?

I don't want to have to go through every view template and have to manually populate each tag with a `data-cms="true"`. Is this possible? How do I go about doing this? Where do I begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-trivial if you don't want to be invasive and there's nothing in place already to identify that content.

My first thought is to decorate the `content` getter with something that embeds it in a `<span>` tag with a `data-` attribute, `html_safe` it, and renders it within the existing `<p>` tag.